# What are the 'inputs' and 'outputs' arguments for tf.saved_mode.simple_save()?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am moving a trained model to production inference.  To do this, I need to save the model so that it (and/or the checkpoints) can be changed at runtime from production run to production run.  Moveover the shapes of the input and output shapes of the model can change from run to run.

So I am looking at [`tf.saved_model.simple_save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/simple_save):

```
simple_save(session, export_dir, inputs={"x": x, "y": y}, outputs={"z": z})
```

If I run inference production code like:

```
session = Session()
inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=(None, height, width, in_channel_size), name='input_img')
model = Some_Model(inputs, num_classes=no_of_defects, is_training=False)
logits, _ = model.build_model()
predictor = tf.nn.softmax(self.logits, name='logits_to_softmax')
feed_dict = {inputs: inputs}
prediction_probabilities = session.run(self.predictor, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Then how do I determine what to enter for `inputs` and `outputs` for:

```
simple_save(session, export_dir, inputs=???, outputs=???)
```

ie What are the 'inputs' and 'outputs' arguments for `tf.saved_mode.simple_save()`?

I am running debugging sessions in PyCharm if that's relevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
simple_save(session, export_dir, inputs={"inputs" : inputs}, outputs={"predictor" : predictor})
```

Comment: Perhaps give some comments on what you're doing to help the OP?

Comment: @sfjac I am the OP.

Comment: Oops. But it would still be nice to provide some prose, not just a one-liner of code, to make the answer more helpful for others.

Answer (score -1):

To my mind, it would be:

```
 simple_save(session, export_dir, inputs=feed_dict, outputs={"predictor" : predictor}))
```

Comment: TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.